# How to remind and confirm an appointment?

Tags: connotations

What is the best informal wording to remind someone about an appointment to get an attendance confirmation? imagine you agreed to meet up with your first in two weeks and want to make sure your friend hasn't forgotten about the catch-up.
Someone may say **"Are we still going to meet tomorrow?"** I think the connotation of this sentence is not quite right. It shows a lack of enthusiasm and also makes it easier for the other person to say some excuses to not show up.

Comment: "Looking forward to seeing you tomorrow!"

Comment: @StuartF I love it.

Comment: How to follow a catch up? What does that mean?? Catching up with someone OK. The bare noun is not usual ere.

Comment: @Lambie “catch-up” is a perfectly cromulent noun. It means an informal meeting.

Comment: In "imagine you agreed to meet up with your first in two weeks", what is a "first in two weeks"? First what???

Comment: @Ben My question was about the whole phrase, not the word catch-up. Why can't you see that??

Comment: @StuartF if you add it like an answer i can mark it as accpeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Looking forward to seeing you tomorrow!

Answer (score 3):

Idiomatically, we say...

> 1: *Are you **still on** for meeting tomorrow?*
> 2: *Are we **still on** for tomorrow's meeting?*
> 3: *Is tomorrows meeting **still on**?*

> **be on**  [<sup><sub>(thefreedictionary)</sub></sup>](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+be+on+one)     definition 5
> **To do something as planned or according to schedule**
> *Are you still on to pick me up from the airport tomorrow?*
> *The meeting is on at five o'clock.*

---

If you think my three example phrasings allow too much encouragement for an unwanted negative answer, you could always include a "tag question" to indicate "expected / desired answer"...

> 4: *We/You're still on for a meeting tomorrow, aren't we/you?*

Comment: If you think ***still*** has a negative connotation in the cited context, you're simply mistaken. "Unlearning" that misconception will be far more useful in helping you to learn idiomatic English than anything I've actually written in my answer. In certain contexts my fourth option might *feasibly* be "demanding" (especially with "pointed" heavy stress on ***...aren't you**?*) - but not usually. It's just an easy way of conveying that ***you*** are still up for the meeting at the same time as asking the other person if they are too.

Comment: This is the way I'd ask most commonly, but there are times I'd want to avoid using "still". It seems like a reasonable concern. For instance, if somebody had recently forgotten a previous appointment and I didn't want to imply I thought they were inconsistent. (That said, I don't think it's always demanding or negative. For instance if I was speaking to a new parent, 'still' shows I'm aware that they might have changing schedules and I respect that)

Comment: @Kaia: If they'd recently forgotten a previous appointment, *anything* you said would imply you thought they were unreliable! With or without the word "still". Best just say nothing and assume they won't be so crass as to forget again.

Answer (score 1):

I think your objection is badly stated. Apparently you want to "catch up" in such a way the you can subtly coerce the other person to meet. In this case you'd do better to say something like, "The meeting is tomorrow. Are you still on?" If you object to "still" (and frankly I don't know why), you can say, "The meeting is tomorrow. Can I count on your attendance?" Of course, this is very formal, and likely to raise alarms in the other person's mind about you throwing your weight around.

Generally, I think you are worrying about the wrong thing. If you are really worried about making it easy for the other to blow you off, you have bigger problems with your relationship.

Comment: Maybe try to focus on the language aspects and avoid giving unsolicited personal advice and judgement.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd - Ah. I guess I wasn't clear. I was discussing the reasons because they affect the language. I assumed the question was hypothetical. Language, particularly in cases like this, is hardly ever neutral. Details of the situation, personalities, and intent affact how you speak.

Answer (score 1):

"Hey boba, just wanted to double-check if we're still on for our catch-up in two weeks. Looking forward to seeing you!"

This wording conveys excitement and anticipation for the meeting, while also politely seeking confirmation from your friend.